# Windows Server 2008 - Access Denied on Folder. Even on Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a folder that I created located C:\SharedFolder on a Windows 2008 Server R2 release. I been able to access it fine all day long, but now for SOME reason I can't even open the folder locally. I'm logged in as the Administrator of the computer, there are no other usernames created on the computer.

I try to open the folder and I get "You don't currently have permission to access this folder"

Then it says "Click continue to permantely get access to this folder."

I click continue then I get..

You have been denied permission to access the folder."

Then it says "To gain access to this folder you will need to use the security tab"

Then i click the security tab and I get..

"You do not have permission to access this objects permission folder" under the Security tab of the folder...

Anyone ever seen this before? I have data in this folder I really need.

Comment: Check this link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/cbebc83f-7a4e-4cc5-b13c-13cf21c6ad25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the original question is you have to reset the permissions to the folder even if your on the administrator account itself. Apparently this was some bug that was apparently fixed in a later patch by microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

I get this problem fairly often in Windows 2008 and if the normal route of taking ownership doesn't work, I can often resolve it by closing any open `Shared Folder Sessions` using the `Computer Management` plugin. Once any open sessions are closed I can get ownership of the folder.

To close open folder sessions (user's whose sessions are closed will lose access to whatever they had open)

- Start -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management
- Computer Managment -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Sessions
- Right-click -> Close Session

Comment: This answer just saved me having to reboot a file server accessed by my whole organization on a constant basis. While the currently selected answer is technically true - I believe this should be the correct answer for the specific question asked since it is a problem originating on a windows share. | Edited: Corrected typos

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of encrypted file system. Also, open WinExplorer and use Security / Advanced / Owner tab to physically take ownership of the folder.

Comment: I would suggest being a little more detailed with your answers, thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, and even doing that, it says "Access denied".

I'm logged in as Administrator, and it *still* won't give me access.

I've tried using an elevated command prompt, and using TAKEOWN or ICACLS, and I still have a folder I can't read.